# Do multi-processors share the same set of registers?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-registers

Do multi-processors share the same set of registers or each processor has its own set of registers? And how about each cpu instead of each processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider the Instruction Pointer register or the Stack Pointer register.  Sharing those would be chaos!